# "You are presented a" / "You are being presented a"

Tags: phrases

I need to employ a similar phrase in an essay but I am not too sure whether this even exists. I think I read it a couple of times in tech blogs but I am not sure if these articles have been written by native English speakers.

What I am trying to say specifically is

```
The viewer is being presented a completely different mindset
```

(Or however I can put it right). What is is supposed to mean is that the text will inform the reader about a certain idea, different from what he is used to read.

Searching for "you are (being) presented a" gives 6 figures of results but there is a huge chunk of results which doesn't fit into the grammatical structure that "my" sentence has.

**tl;dr**: Is a phrase "you are presented something" or "you are being presented something" grammatically correct when it refers to a text that you read or does this phrase even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘The viewer is presented with ...’ and ‘The viewer is being presented with ...’ are both correct grammatically. The difference is that one is present simple passive, and the other is present continuous passive.

Which you use depends on the context.

‘The dog is walked *daily* around the park’, is an example of the present simple passive. ‘The dog is being walked around the park *as we speak*’, is an example of present simple continuous. I’ve highlighted some key words there.

Generally, you use the first when it is a recurring action, and the second when it is something presently happening, though the uses of them spread much further than this.

I would suggest, as you say the text *will* inform the reader, that you begin with either ‘The viewer will be presented ...’, or ‘The viewer is to be presented ...’.